# Select the Latest Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I'm trying to aggregate 3 rows to one row (select the latest record). But I still get 3 records instead of 1. Any thoughts ? ** SQL Server**

```
select [TotalTechPremium] From Premiumfile
where [TimeDate Stamp] = (select Max([TimeDate Stamp]) 
                          From Premiumfile
                          where PolicyNo = '47-ZCA-000276-02'
                         );
```

Comment: Why didn't you just use TOP 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data and expected results are also so important when asking a T-SQL question.

As you haven't provided this, this is a guess, but a common way of getting the "latest" record is using a CTE and `ROW_NUMBER`. An example query would look like:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT [YourColumns]
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [RelevantColumns] ORDER BY [TimestampColumn] DESC) AS RN
    FROM [YourTable])
SELECT [YourColumns]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

If this doesn't help, have a look at http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/ on Forum Etiquette on how to post a T-SQL Question.

Comment: No need to use a CTE here as well, just ROW_NUMBER() is enough, with another SELECT wrapped round it. ROW_NUMBER() is extremely useful, and fast.

Comment: @TDP the CTE is required, you can't reference `ROW_NUMBER` in the `WHERE`, and doing 2 selects would mean scanning the table twice; which isn't required. CTE is the better choice.

Comment: The execution plans are identical. I've added a test scenario as an answer. Unless the execution plans are different for # tables?...

Comment: Oh, @TDP, you mean using a subquery. Personally, I prefer a CTE; I find them much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different ways of using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
create table #t (id1 int, id2 int)

insert into #t
select 1,1 union
select 1,2 union
select 2,1 union
select 2,2

select * from #t

;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT id1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id2 ORDER BY id1 DESC) AS RN
    FROM #t)
SELECT id1
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;

select id1 from (
    SELECT id1,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id2 ORDER BY id1 DESC) AS RN
    FROM #t
) z
where rn = 1

drop table #t
```

If you set Include Actual Executions Plans and execute the above you can see that the executions plans are identical.

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple records with the same timestamp.

This might help:

```
select pf.TotalTechPremium
From Premiumfile pf
where pf.PolicyNo = '47-ZCA-000276-02'
      pf.[TimeDate Stamp] = (select Max(pf2.[TimeDate Stamp]) 
                             From pf2.Premiumfile
                             where pf2.PolicyNo = pf.PolicyNo
                            );
```

But if you want one row, I would just do:

```
select top (1) pf.TotalTechPremium
From Premiumfile pf
where pf.PolicyNo = '47-ZCA-000276-02'
order by pf.[TimeDate Stamp] desc;
```

Comment: Only reason I can, personally, think of is that the first query requires 2 scans. I do wish people would comment when they downvote; I'm all for criticism; provided it's constructive.

Comment: @Lamu . . . With the right indexes, this should be more efficient than the answers using `row_number()`.

Answer (score -1):

If that query outputs 3 records, it means that there are 3 records in the table PremiumFile with a Timestamp equal to the maximum timestamp for that policy number.
Maybe you are forgetting to add an additional where where you filter again by that Policy number.
Or maybe you can replace your query by:

```
select top 1 TotalTechPremium
from Premiumfile
where PolicyNo='47-ZCA-000276-02'
order by Timestamp desc
```